Looking for pointers to find faulty component(s) causing low voltage to light sockets from a ceiling fan control board
I'm troubleshooting this universal fan speed control board which also controls power to the lightbulb sockets in the same fixture. This module is commonly found in popular ceiling fan products (at least here in Canada).
The symtom is very dim light coming from the bulbs which I traced down to low voltage (~ 5V AC) coming out of the control module as shown here. I've confirmed that when I toggle the light button on the remote control I see the voltage drop to 0 and then when I turn it back on it only ever returns to the dim 5V level. Actually, I also observed that when I turn the fan off completely, the voltage to the light fixtures bumped up to just over 6V so that may give a clue.
I don't think we've seen a noticeable change in the fan speed or strength so I'm thinking the problem may be isolated to the light socket outputs only but it could also be that a drop in power to the fans might not be as obvious to see as the dim lightbulbs.
My uneducated hunch goes to the two big capacitors at the center of this circuit but it's nothing more than a hunch. I'm still quite new to the hobby of electronics test and repair so I'm reaching out to you more experienced folks to give me some pointers on where to start my troubleshooting. Thanks!





Please post a schematic
